# How I can make autorestarts golang application in Docker container?

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose

I have the Docker container with Golang and Mongo. I want to make telegram bot, and I want to auto recompile/rerun my go application when I change source code.
I tried to use [mitranim/gow](https://github.com/mitranim/gow,) but it didn't work.

What I need to use for auto rerun my go application after change source code? I need anything seems nodemon for nodejs, but for go

Here my [docker-compose](https://pastebin.com/Btn27wQ7) and [dockerfile](https://pastebin.com/Btn27wQ7) configs.

```
My host machine is win10
```

Comment: Something like this: https://github.com/codegangsta/gin ?

Comment: Yes, thanks. But it looks like strange, when I run "gin --all -i run main.go" handly after connect to docker with "docker exec -it machninename /bin/bash" it works, but If I write it command in dockerfile like "RUN ["gin", "--all", "-i", "run", "main.go"]" it build once and don't recompile after changes.

Comment: I found, if I mark file changed in docker terminal with command "touch" it works. But if I change files in editor from host machine (windows) it doesn't work. It seems trouble docker on windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most file monitoring tools on Linux use as their preferred mechanism [inotify](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html). The tool you mentioned [mitranim/gow](https://github.com/mitranim/gow) seems to fall into the same category.

The issue is that a change to the filesystem in Windows does not cause the Linux guest to publish the event. This is kind of expected because Windows doesn't "know" a watch has been set, and therefore cannot notify the Linux container when a file has changed. It is a common problem for virtualized environments or other cross-platform / over-the-network file system sharing solutions.

There is similar issue you might want to have a look to: [Inotify on shared drives does not work](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/56)

A possible solution to the problem is to use polling. `nodemon` has a `legacyWatch` flag and can run any command when a file changes:

> In some networked environments (such as a container running nodemon
>   reading across a mounted drive), you will need to use the legacyWatch:
>   true which enables Chokidar's polling.

Example:

```
nodemon --legacy-watch <working-dir> -e go --exec "go run main.go"
```

Or use `nodemon` in combination with other monitoring tools by having `nodemon` touching a file when it detects a file change (kind of a hack):

```
nodemon --legacy-watch <working-dir> -e go --exec "touch main.go"
```